# Ошибка доступа при попытке программно включить вспышку на WP8 устройстве

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
public PhotoCamera cam = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
private void flash_on(bject sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.on;
}
```

Пытаюсь включить вспышку (как фонарик), но выдает ошибку на строке *cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.on;*

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException не обработано пользовательским кодом
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
  Source=Windows
  StackTrace:
       at Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureDevice.GetSupportedPropertyValues(CameraSensorLocation sensor, Guid propertyId)
       at Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera.IsFlashModeSupported(FlashMode mode)
       at Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera.set_FlashMode(FlashMode value)
       at PhoneApp1.MainPage.falshlight_power(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Наверное для работы с железом нужны админские права, а то будут всякие юзер моде проги включать и выключать вспышку.

Comment: @cpp_user, можно чуть подробнее, просто только начинаю путь разработчика

Comment: @cpp_user это вам не андроид

Comment: Тем не менее у него "Access is denied."

Comment: @KirillSemenov точно не помню в каком месте, кажеться или в настройках проекта или в манифесте проекта можно указать к чему будет доступ у данного приложения, поищите в этом направлении. Вас конкретно интересует доступ к камере

Comment: @Dmitry Спасибо, в манифесте добавил камеру, но теперь другая ошибка) 'You cannot use this instance until it is fully initialized. You can initialize by passing this Camera object to VideoBrush.SetSource(...)'

Comment: `System.InvalidOperationException не обработано пользовательским кодом
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=You cannot use this instance until it is fully initialized. You can initialize by passing this Camera object to VideoBrush.SetSource(...)
  Source=Microsoft.Devices.Camera`

Comment: @KirillSemenov сейчас обновлю свой ответ

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

открыть файл *WMAppManifent.xml*
добавить

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>
```

после этого ваш код должен заработать

**UPD:**

```
private PhotoCamera _photoCamera;
private VideoBrush _videoBrush;

// Check to see if the camera is available on the device.
if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary))
{
    // Use standard camera on back of device.
    _photoCamera = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);

    // Event is fired when the PhotoCamera object has been initialized.
    _photoCamera.Initialized += PhotoCamera_Initialized;

    // Add the photo camera to the video source
    _videoBrush = new VideoBrush();
    _videoBrush.SetSource(_photoCamera);
}

private void PhotoCamera_Initialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if flash mode is supported on the device.
    if (_photoCamera.IsFlashModeSupported(FlashMode.On))
    {
        // Turn the flash on.
        _photoCamera.FlashMode = FlashMode.On;
        _photoCamera.Focus();
    }
}
```

код взять с [английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558449/wp7-flashlight-application-error)

Comment: К сожалению не включается,  слышно как работает фокус но вспышки нет.

Comment: @KirillSemenov вот есть еще ссылка на решение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847510/toggle-flashlight-in-windows-phone-8-1